# Retrieve remote system information using Java

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, mac-address

I have a project requirement for which I need to store the information of a users system like OS, MAC address, etc. whenever he visits the website so that we can uniquely identify the user's machine. I am developing the project in Spring MVC 3.1.
Currently we are using IP address and User agent using JavaScript but both of them are not reliable and can be easily changed.
Is there a way to do this through Java/JavaScript/Spring MVC.
Thanks in advance.

The same user can register multiple times. To avoid this, we need to identify the user's machine

Comment: *"so that we can uniquely identify the user"*  Have the users log-in or otherwise don't be so nosy.

Comment: What data is it that you need? Anything that can be sent as a request header/parameter can be faked, so there's no 100% bullet proof solution.

Comment: I understand that the request header can be faked. So, I need to know if there is another way to gather the user's system information.

Comment: How do you define a user? Same person? Same Machine (Computer, Mobile, etc.)? Same browser? you should define all that in order to get an answer.

Comment: By user I mean same machine. I will add this in the description of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to uniquely identify the user, use cookies.
When a user enter your website, check if he has your cookie. If so, use it, it will identify the user. If not, create a cookie for him with something like UUID.
You can use both Java and JavaScript to put and get cookies from the user.

Comment: Cookies can easily be removed from a system. They do not serve the purpose of uniquely identifying the user

Comment: Seems like you want to achieve authentication without authentication.

Comment: We are authenticating the user. But we need an extra level of security.